# Nagios 3.5 can't send notification email despite nagios logs ok / centos6

Tags: centos, email-server, centos6, nagios

I spent hours trying to make nagios send email notification.
my contact configuration is quite simple : I juste have one : nagiosadmin, and he is the default contact.

In /var/log/nagios.log, nagios tend to send email, so it's not a matter of contact configuration.
When I copy paste the command found in the log file in the console, the mail is sent and I received it. (I tested it with users : root & nagios - for both of them it's OK).

Here is the /var/log/nagios.log lines :

```
[1405635099] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;m1;PING;CUSTOM (CRITICAL);notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL - Time to live exceeded (m1);Nagios Admin;11..11
[1405635130] Warning: Contact 'nagiosadmin' service notification command '/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: CUSTOM\n\nService: PING\nHost: m1\nAddress: m1\nState: CRITICAL\n\nDate/Time: Fri Jul 18 00:11:39 CEST 2014\n\nAdditional Info:\n\nCRITICAL - Time to live exceeded (m1)\n" | /bin/mail -s "** CUSTOM Service Alert: m1/PING is CRITICAL **" myEmail@gmail.com' timed out after 30 seconds
```

after reading some serverfault Q&A, I tried to add 'from' parameter :

- -r fromEmail@.. : for mail from adresse
- -- -f fromEmail@..

but I don't receive the emails.

I have no other clue for finding the solution.. what would be good to test in order to determine which component has trouble sending email ?

Comment: are you using selinux?

Comment: `Warning: Contact ... timed out after 30 seconds` - The mail command timed out.  Try manually sending an email with the `mail` command from the command line.  Is your MTA properly configured?  When you run it from the command line, make sure you run it as the nagios service account.

Comment: @c4f4t0r : yes, I'm using selinux, it was there when installing my centos6 openvz template (/proxmox)
@Zoredache : yes, when I copy paste the same command as given in the logs, I receive the mail. I, of course, also receive a mail when I do a simple `mail -s "mySubject" myMail.gmail.com`

Comment: @c4f4t0r hum... after some checks.. I got a "SELinux is disabled" when doing a `getsebool -a` .. so it shouldn't come from SELinux..

Comment: I also tried to install postfix instead of 'sendmail'... and I had the same result : the mail are ok when I enter the command given in nagios.log file, but nagios itself can't send mail (or it sends it and something goes wrong after..)

Comment: what's the mail log say?